# How can I view SQL Generated by Visual Studio DataSource?

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, visual-studio, debugging

I've got a data source in Visual Studio. Is there any way to view the SQL that it generates before it sends it to the database?
I don't just want to see the SelectComand, InsertCommand properties which are part of the asp:SqlDataSource, I want to see the query once the parameters have been filled. Is it possible to do this from Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be possible. See the other answer for a possible work around.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know the answer, but for such debugging I use SQL profiler.

Edit:
For the Oracle, check TKPROF tool. Documentation is [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/sqltrace.htm#sthref2019).

You might also need to

```
alter session set events '10046 TRACE NAME CONTEXT FOREVER, LEVEL 12';
```

Comment: always the best choice to see what's **REALLY** sent to SQL Server! ;-)

Comment: But sadly it won't work in my case . . . as I'm using Oracle :)